# ASP.NET Core localization not working in _Layout head

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a `_Layout.cshtml` in my MVC project, where I want to set the page `<title>` via ASP.NET Core localization.

This is a (simplified) repro:

```
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources> SharedLocalizer;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@SharedLocalizer["My Default Language Text"]</title>
</head>
<body>
    @SharedLocalizer["My Default Language Text"]
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

The resource in `body` is being localized correctly and renders the text from the resource file as expected. But the resource in `head` is not and stays "My Default Language Text" no matter what I try.

Please note that I see this behaviour in both cases:

1. Use a shared resource via `@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources> SharedLocalizer` (like in the code above)
2. Or when I use a `IViewLocalizer` via `@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer Localizer`

I'm running `v1.1.3` of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found that my problem was related to this bug: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/277 (non-english localization as the default localization).

Comment: Is there a fix?

Comment: Not entirely sure, afaics it's already fixed in some 2.0 build, but not for 1.* (it's actually a .NET Core issue, not an ASP.NET Core one).